# Replacing the WP.me URL shortener with Bit.ly

Tags: shortlink

I am setting up a big blog for a client and we're looking to replace the wp.me shortlinks in the header and in everything with our custom domain on bit.ly.

I have working code to build the Shortlinks, im just wondering if there is any way to replace the functions so pressing "Get Shortlink" and tweeting links, would use our bit.ly

Is there a way to add action and replace the existing wp_get_shortlink and a like?
To be clear, i want all the same functionality, just with a different short link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible, here is a great walkthough: http://bavotasan.com/2010/create-bit-ly-short-urls-for-your-posts-in-wordpress/

Bullet points:

-Write a function that gets the bitly link upon publish

-Remove the default action and add your own

-Call wp_get_shortlink() like normal and bitly will be used

Comment: Bit.ly has released their own official plugin to do all this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/bitly/